# 2 div alignment in mobile device

Tags: css, css-float, html

I have problem in aligning the div in mobile device.

My code is like

Some text



Some text

When I sink the screen Rfloatdiv div is coming down, I want Lfloatdiv should go down instead Rfloatdiv div.. Got my point?

Please help me.

Comment: PLease share you html markup with us

Comment: <div class="wrapper">
<div class="RFloatdiv">
    Some text here
</div>
<div class="LFloatdiv">
   Some text here
</div>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

There is stacking order when you use `float`. Basically, floated elements stack up to the parent edge, then move down for the next available edge.
The order they appear in HTML is important!

If you have:

```
<article>
    <!-- ORDER MATTER -->

    <div id="left">This is left div</div>
    <div id="right">This is the right div</div>

</article>
```

And in css:

```
#left {
    float: left;
}

#right {
    float: right;
}
```

Output for small screen will be:

```
This is left div
This is the right div
```

But changing the order they appear in HTML will modify what happens when the screen is smaller.

Play with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/732Ly/1/
Change the float to left left or right right in that fiddle and see the results!.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you asked for:
http://jsfiddle.net/c2DMN/1/embedded/result/

You can view the source code, I worked on:
http://jsfiddle.net/c2DMN/1

Here is html code:

```
<div class="wrapper"><div class="Rdiv">RDiv</div><div class="Ldiv">LDiv</div></div>
```

And Css code:

```
.Rdiv{background:Red;float:right;width:200px;height:100px;}.Ldiv{background:Blue;float:left;width:200px;height:100px;}.wrapper{background:Green;height:200px;width:500px;}
```

Please mark it helpful if it is :D

Comment: can you post your current html and css?